# "SUM" in cells, with "POI" (3.17)

Tags: apache-poi

I want to do the sum of a range of cells for each row of my excel. And I do it like this:

```
String strFormulaTarifaTotal = "SUMA(" + cellTotalTarifaHorasNormales.getAddress().formatAsString() + ":"
            + cellTarifaGuardias.getAddress().formatAsString() + ")";
    Cell cellTarifaTotalProduccion = rowDatosEmpleado.createCell(cellnum++);
    cellTarifaTotalProduccion.setCellFormula(strFormulaTarifaTotal);
    UtilsPOI.cellBordeNegro(workbook, cellTarifaTotalProduccion);
```

When I open my excel, I see that it does not do well and when looking at the formula in the excel I see that it has put me: "=sum(V5:Y5)" instead of "=SUM(V5:Y5)".

When debugging in java I see that it is capitalized. I do not know in what process, I imagine that POI passes it from uppercase to lowercase, nor how can I prevent it from doing so to execute my formula well.

Comment: POI works, the same as the excel file format, with the english language formula constants. What happens if you use the English form `SUM` in your formula?

Comment: It's the first thing I put, but I was not going. I work with "SUMA" but not with "SUM" or with "sum".

Comment: Gagravarr You were right, if I put SUM directly in the excel it does not work, but if I put it in the Java code, it works. Thank you very much.